# Reading two numbers with whitespace as a single number from a file

Tags: c++, file, int, ifstream, cin

The part of my input file I run into the problem is:

3   North Carolina  26-5    147 4   3

My input File is formatted as:

INT \t STRING \t INT-INT \t INT \t INT...

pos \t name \t wins-loss \t vote \t lPos...

The problem here is 147 and 4 are intended to be read as 1474, from an "accidental" tab in the input. Is this possible to input validate like Im picturing? The following 3 must of course be read as a separate int.

EDIT: This line would be the only line with an "accidental" tab. All others would be proper.

Any solutions I have tried so far end up eating the follwoing 3 and sometimes more, ruining the file read.

```
while (inFile >> input.pos)
{
    inFile >> input.name;
after, read it also
    if ((inFile >> ws).peek() > 64 && (inFile >> ws).peek() < 91)
    {
        inFile >> name2;
        input.name += ' ' + name2;
    }
    inFile >> input.wins;
    inFile.ignore(1, '-');
    inFile >> input.loss;
    inFile >> input.vote;        //PROBLEM LIES HERE
    if ((inFile >> ws).peek() == '-')
    {
        input.lPos = 0;
        inFile.ignore(1, '-');
    }
    else
        inFile >> input.lPos;
    sList.insertAfter(input);   //Insert completed input
}
```

As always, thanks in advance for any time or help, much appreciated!

Comment: I would read these as two strings, concatenate the strings, and then call `stoi`.

Comment: Does every line in your input file have this "accidental" tab? Only some? Only this one?

Comment: The only problem here would be making sure the program knows to not to merge two numbers from a proper input such as: "4 foo bar 13-11 70 10", and create 7010 while not having a number to read into lPos.

Comment: Apologies, only this line would have the "accidental" tab. I'll update the post.

Comment: How would you know whether it's  1474 3 or  147 43?

Comment: The problem is not with your program, the problem is with the input file. It contains invalid input. So really, the solution here is to fix the input file